# Wordpress searchandfilter plugin and php code result problem

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new in this forum. Looking for a solution for my problem in wordpress template file. Maybe someone can help to solve it. This is my template file code

```
<?php

/* 
Template name: recipies
*/

get_header();?>

<header class="entry-header "> 
    <h1 class="entry-title">Recipies</h1> 
</header>

<?php 

$pack_expire = 0;

$sub_pack = WPUF_Subscription::get_user_pack( get_current_user_id() );

$allowed_packs = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpuf_res_subscription', true );

if ( !$sub_pack ) {
    $pack_expire=1;
}

$pack_id = is_array( $sub_pack ) ? intval( $sub_pack['pack_id'] ) : 0;

if ( !$pack_id ) {
    $pack_expire=1;
}

// check expiration
$expire = isset( $sub_pack['expire'] ) ? $sub_pack['expire'] : 0;

if ( strtolower( $expire ) == 'unlimited' || empty( $expire ) ) {
    $has_expired = false;
} 
else if ( ( strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $expire ) ) ) >= strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d', time() ) ) ) ) {
    $has_expired = false;
} else {
    $has_expired = true;
}

if ( $has_expired ) {
    $pack_expire=1;
} 

$pack_id = is_array( $sub_pack ) ? intval( $sub_pack['pack_id'] ) : 0;

if ( ! in_array( $pack_id, $allowed_packs ) ) {
    $pack_expire=1;
} 

if($pack_expire==0){?>


<div class="container recipes-boxes">
    <div class="row media-justify-content mt-0">

 
<div class="col-sm-12 mb-4">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[searchandfilter id="1003"]');?> <!-- Searchandfilter plugin -->
</div>
               
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 img-container">
        <h2 class="text-center"><a class="r-shadow" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ;?></a></h2>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        
        <h6 class="recipe-list-comment"><a class="shadow" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Comment</a></h6>
    </div>   
    
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php echo the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 1 ) );?>

<?php else : ?>
             <p><?php _e( 'No recipes found' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>


<div class="container my-5">

<?php }else{

  echo '<a href="/payment/?section=subscription" class="nav-link">Pay now</a>';

} ?>


</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

The problem is, when search doesn't find any result, show message "Pay now" instead "No recipes found". I dont know how to fix it. Maybe someone can check where is the problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: These divs are not closed: `<div class="container recipes-boxes">
    <div class="row media-justify-content mt-0">`

Comment: I suggest for you to add a `var_dump($pack_expire); die` line before to `if($pack_expire==0): ?>` line to check the value is  correct or not here

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Good point, div are now closed. But problem still exists. I try to add `var_dump($pack_expire); die;` before `if($pack_expire==0){` And I get two result.If search returns something, show `int(1)` if search did not find anything show int(0)